# Properly setting up a check constraint with Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this check_constraint in my model.

```
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @all_fields)
    |> validate_required(@required_fields)
    |> check_constraint(:stars, name: :stars_range, message: "stars must be between 1 and 5")
  end
```

The create constraint was successfully migrated.

```
create constraint("reviews", "stars_range", check: "stars>=1 and stars<=5")
```

But when I run this test the changeset is valid? I would expect it to be invalid because I'm passing the integer 7 to the `stars` column. which has the constraint of `1 through 5`. Does anybody know what is wrong here?

```
test "requires stars to be within range of 1-5" do
    user = insert(:user)
    project = insert(:project, owner: user)
    user_project_map = %{project_id: project.id, user_id: user.id}
    review_map = Map.merge(@valid_attrs, user_project_map)

    attrs = %{review_map | stars: 7}
    changeset = Review.changeset(%Review{}, attrs)
    refute changeset.valid?
  end
```

Comment: did you try this ? validate_inclusion(:stars, 1..5) ? ref https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html

Comment: `validate_inclusion` -- Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#check_constraint/3):

> (...) Now, when invoking Repo.insert/2 or Repo.update/2, if the price is not positive, it will be converted into an error and {:error, changeset} returned by the repository. Note that the error will occur only after hitting the database so it will not be visible until all other validations pass.

This means that `check_constraint` happens only if the query hits the database. Hence your `changeset.valid?` returning `true` when you check the validation before the database is actually called. The constraint you created is created inside database so Ecto actually has no way of knowing what this constraint actually checks for before calling it. Usually such constraints are used for more complex checks or if you have constraints already defined in your database (perhaps because you migrated the database from another system?). If you want to see your constraint in action you should just write in your test:

```rb
attrs = %{review_map | stars: 7}
changeset = Review.changeset(attrs)
{:error, changeset} = Repo.insert(changeset)
refute changeset.valid?
```

If you need the `Changeset` to check some conditions before calling the database then you should use functions like `validate_inclusion/4` or `validate_subset/4`. You can even write your own checker using `validate_change/4` (let me know if you need more explanation how to do it). If you use those validators then your changeset will work before calling the database.

Answer (score 0):

In [my answer to your previous question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959805/migration-database-constraint) if I add some output when creating a changeset for an insert:

```
defmodule Foo do
  alias Foo.Review
  require Logger

  @repo Foo.Repo

  def list_reviews do
    @repo.all(Review)
  end

  def insert_review(attrs) do
    changeset = Review.changeset(%Review{}, attrs)

    ##   HERE ###
    Logger.debug("changeset.valid? => #{changeset.valid?}")

    @repo.insert(changeset)
  end

  def delete_book(%Book{}=book) do
    @repo.delete(book)
  end

end
```

here is the output in iex:

```
ex(3)> reviews = Foo.list_reviews                         
[debug] QUERY OK source="reviews" db=3.4ms
SELECT r0."id", r0."title", r0."contents", r0."stars", r0."inserted_at", r0."updated_at" FROM "reviews" AS r0 []
[]


## VALID DATA ###

iex(4)> Foo.insert_review(%{title: "book", contents: "good", stars: 4})  
[debug] changeset.valid? => true
[debug] QUERY OK db=2.3ms queue=2.0ms
INSERT INTO "reviews" ("contents","stars","title","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id" ["good", 4, "book", ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:06], ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:06]]
{:ok,
 %Foo.Review{
   __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "reviews">,
   contents: "good",
   id: 4,
   inserted_at: ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:06],
   stars: 4,
   title: "book",
   updated_at: ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:06]
 }}


## INVALID DATA ##

iex(5)> Foo.insert_review(%{title: "movie", contents: "shite", stars: 0})
[debug] changeset.valid? => true
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=6.1ms queue=1.5ms
INSERT INTO "reviews" ("contents","stars","title","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id" ["shite", 0, "movie", ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:16], ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:16]]
{:error,
 #Ecto.Changeset<
   action: :insert,
   changes: %{contents: "shite", stars: 0, title: "movie"},
   errors: [
     stars: {"stars must be between 1 and 5 (inclusive)",
      [constraint: :check, constraint_name: "stars_range"]}
   ],
   data: #Foo.Review<>, 
   valid?: false
 >}
```

For the invalid data, you can see that the changeset is valid before calling `@repo.insert(changeset)`, and then after the insert fails Ecto returns an invalid changeset.

That's because a check constraint is a db rule--not a validator. The changeset() function applies all the validators that you specify and thereby determines if the changeset is valid. If the changeset is valid, then Ecto actually tries to do the insert in the db. At that point, the db executes the check constraint to determine if the insert will succeed or not. If the check constraint fails, the db throws an error.  Ecto catches that error then adds the message you specified here:

```
   |> check_constraint(
        :stars,
        name: :stars_range,
        message: "stars must be between 1 and 5 (inclusive)"
      )
```

to the errors in the changeset, sets `changeset.valid?` to `false`, then returns `{:error, changeset}`.

There is a difference in the output when a validator fails v. when a check constraint fails.  If I change the validations to:

```
  def changeset(%Foo.Review{}=review, attrs \\ %{}) do
    review
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :contents, :stars])
    |> validate_required(:title)  ##<==== ADDED THIS VALIDATION
    |> check_constraint(
        :stars,
        name: :stars_range,
        message: "stars must be between 1 and 5 (inclusive)"
      )
  end
```

then try to do an insert without a title, here's the output:

```
iex(6)> Foo.insert_review(%{contents: "crowded", stars: 1})
[debug] changeset.valid? => false
{:error,
 #Ecto.Changeset<
   action: :insert,
   changes: %{contents: "crowded", stars: 1},
   errors: [title: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
   data: #Foo.Review<>,
   valid?: false
 >}
```

Compare to:

```
## INVALID DATA ##

iex(5)> Foo.insert_review(%{title: "movie", contents: "shite", stars: 0})
[debug] changeset.valid? => true
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=6.1ms queue=1.5ms
INSERT INTO "reviews" ("contents","stars","title","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id" ["shite", 0, "movie", ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:16], ~N[2019-07-10 17:23:16]]
{:error,
 #Ecto.Changeset<
   action: :insert,
   changes: %{contents: "shite", stars: 0, title: "movie"},
   errors: [
     stars: {"stars must be between 1 and 5 (inclusive)",
      [constraint: :check, constraint_name: "stars_range"]}
   ],
   data: #Foo.Review<>, 
   valid?: false
 >}
```

In the latter output, note:

```
 [debug] QUERY ERROR db=6.1ms queue=1.5ms
```

The difference in output indicates that only after all validations pass does Ecto attempt to execute the insert. When the insert is actually executed, then the db applies the check constraint, which causes the insert to fail, and ecto logs a `QUERY ERROR`.

The bottom line is: just because a changeset is valid does not mean that an insert will succeed.  If the `changeset()` function adds `constraints` to the db, then you can't know whether inserting a changeset will succeed until you actually execute the insert by calling `@repo.insert(changeset)`.